# Crash at NSString replaceCharactersInRange

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring

I have the following code:

```
-(void) swapCharacters: (NSMutableString *) set : (NSInteger) first : (NSInteger) second    {

NSLog(@"swap: set = '%@', first = '%d', second = '%d'", set, first, second);
NSRange rangeSecond = NSMakeRange((NSUInteger) second, 1);
NSRange rangeFirst = NSMakeRange((NSUInteger) first, 1);

[set replaceCharactersInRange:rangeSecond withString:[set substringWithRange:rangeFirst]];
}
```

NSLog print is : set = 'happy', first = '0', second = '0'
But the program crashes at [set rangeFirst = ...........] without any debug info.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What does the console say? what's the crash?  Try NSLogging the NSRanges before calling `[set `

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8682269/objective-c-parameters-not-passes-properly

Comment: There is no log.  When I tried to NSLog ranges, it also crashes.

Comment: NSRage is a C structure so you need to log it like this : NSLog(@"%d , %d", rangeFirst.location, rangeFirst.length);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just try your code and it's working for me like this

```
-(void) swapCharacters: (NSMutableString *) set first: (NSInteger) first second: (NSInteger) second    {

NSLog(@"swap: set = '%@', first = '%d', second = '%d'", set, first, second);
NSRange rangeSecond = NSMakeRange((NSUInteger) second, 1);
NSRange rangeFirst = NSMakeRange((NSUInteger) first, 1);

[set replaceCharactersInRange:rangeSecond withString:[set substringWithRange:rangeFirst]];
}
```

And I'm calling it like this

```
NSMutableString *s = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"Hello"];
[self swapCharacters:s first:0 second:3];
NSLog(@"s == %@", s);
```

And this is the NSLog I get :

> 2011-12-30 15:13:48.822 tabbar[908:207] swap: set = 'Hello', first = '0', second = '3'
>   2011-12-30 15:13:48.823 tabbar[908:207] s == HelHo

---

Are you passing a NSMutableString or a NSString to that method when you are calling it?
Passing a NSString it's the only way I'm able to make that code crash.

Comment: Thanks.  Somewhere in the chain of calls I was assigning a NSString to a NSMutuableString.  I corrected it and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I found a few things that should be changed in your code. Here is what I did to make your swap function work.

This is the function:

```
-(void) swapCharacters: (NSMutableString *)set withInteger: (int)first andInteger: (int)second{

NSLog(@"swap: set = '%@', first = '%i', second = '%i'", set, first, second);
NSRange rangeSecond = NSMakeRange(second, 1);
NSRange rangeFirst = NSMakeRange(first, 1);

[set replaceCharactersInRange:rangeSecond withString:[set substringWithRange:rangeFirst]];
NSLog(@"swap: set = '%@', first = '%i', second = '%i'", set, first, second);
}
```

This is how the function was called:

```
FooClass *fooObjectVar = [[FooClass alloc] init];

NSMutableString *myString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"Hello"];

[fooObjectVar swapCharacters:myString withInteger:0 andInteger:0];

[fooObjectVar release];
[myString release];
```

This is the output:

```
2011-12-30 14:19:00.501 StackOverflowHelp[748:903] swap: set = 'Hello', first = '0', second = '0'
2011-12-30 14:19:00.504 StackOverflowHelp[748:903] swap: set = 'Hello', first = '0', second = '0'
```

*Notice that with functions in objective-c, the name is like a description

*Instead of using NSInteger, I used a normal int because an NSInteger is not necessary here

*When using **NSLog** or string formatting, **%@** is for objects (NSString,NSInteger...), **%i** is for int, **%f** is for float and **%d** is for double

I hope that helped, happy coding!

Comment: Thanks for the extra time you spent to explain some very good points.

Comment: I made a mistake in my response when I used NSInteger as an example of an object; NSInteger is not an object and is in fact just a long int. Sorry about that.